# Div abrindo e fechando automaticamente

Tags: jquery

Bom, eu irei colocar ADS em uma página minha, e ele ficará no topo da página centralizado.
E eu queria que ao a pessoa entrar na página o ads mostrasse, e teria uma função de close (X), e depois de 5 minutos abrisse novamente, e assim vai, a cada 5 minutos abririanovamente o ADS.

Tenho esse código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html
PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>
<head>
    <title>Efeitos com jQuery</title>
    <script language="javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ocultar").click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      $("#capaefectos").hide("slow");
    });

    $("#mostrar").click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      $("#capaefectos").show(1000);
    });
});
</script>
<style>
body {
    background: black;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
 <center>
<div id="capaefectos" style="background-color: #cc7700; color:fff; padding:10px;width: 800px;height: 100px;border-radius: 10px;">

  <p>Camada de Efeitos</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>Aqui você pode colocar o qualquer coisa!</p>
</div>

<p>
<a href="#" id="ocultar">Ocultar a camada</a> | 
<a href="#" id="mostrar">Mostrar a camada</a>  
</p>
 </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Mas eu não queria que aparecesse esse ocultar camada e mostrar camada, eu queria que aparecesse um "X" na direita do ads e que ele abrisse a cada 5 minutos.

Comment: Já tens algum código? HTML ou JavaScript?

Comment: Eu ainda não tenho.

Comment: Paulo, ser não tens HTML nem JS esta pergunta fica muito ampla pois dá para fazer de muitas maneiras diferentes. Faz a parte de HTML e coloca aqui o código e qual a div que tem os ads. Assim é mais objetiva a pergunta e podemos ajudar com a parte de JS.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, então as mudanças que tens de no HTML é colocar `<a href="#" id="ocultar">Ocultar a camada</a>` dentro de `#capaefectos` e mudar esse texto "Ocultar a camada" para simplesmente `X`. O JS (event handler) pode ser o mesmo, mas dentro da função que fecha a div podes diretamente disparar o contador para a proxima abertura, 5 mins depois. Como o JavaScript trabalha em milisegundos 5 minutos é 5 * 60 * 1000 ms.

Então o HTML pode ser:

```
<div id="capaefectos" style="background-color: #cc7700; color:fff; padding:10px;width: 800px;height: 100px;border-radius: 10px;">

  <p>Camada de Efeitos</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>Aqui você pode colocar o qualquer coisa!</p>
  <a href="#" id="ocultar">X</a>
</div>
```

e o JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ocultar").click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      $("#capaefectos").hide("slow"); // esconder
      setTimeout(function(){          // temporizador
          $("#capaefectos").show();
      }, 5 * 60 * 1000);
    });
    $("#capaefectos").show(); // mostrar quando a página carrega
});
```

Comment: Cara, valeu, muito obrigado, resolvido.

Comment: @Train se a resposta atendeu o que você precisava, marque-a como correta clicando no "check" do lado esquerdo.